# Advantages of functional component in React? And why the react team suggest it's the feature of react components?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react. And when I start to react most of the documents in react and the react conf video resource said use functional component instead of the class-based component. And they also said if you want to manage state and use lifecycle go with hooks.

I want to know what are the advantages of the functional component in react?

And why the react team suggests that functional-based approach while creating components in react?

Can anyone answer that or give me some source to understand this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reasons as follows to use:

1. Functional component are much easier to read and test because they
   are plain JavaScript functions without state or lifecycle-hooks
2. You end up with less code
3. It will get easier to separate
       container    and    presentational components because you need to
       think more about    your    component’s state if you don’t have
       access to setState() in    your    component
4. The React team mentioned that there may be a performance boost for
   functional component in future React versions
5. There is one difference is the syntax. A functional
   component is just a plain JavaScript function which accepts props as
   an argument and returns a React element. A class component requires
   you to extend from React.Component and create a render function
   which returns a React element. This requires more code but will also
   give some benefits

Comment: A couple of your points only make sense in a pre-hook version of react. Functional components now can have state and the equivalent of lifecycles, and can thus can be used both for presentational and container components.

Comment: Is there any other advantages @NicholasTower and Saket Agarwal?

Comment: these are only as preferred @MariSelvan, mostly functional components are for reducing the code and reducing the power of this reference, making the code more readable, for following the OOP concepts, but its mostly upto the user to where and how to use..!